# ICMP ping one way only?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, icmp

I have 2 W7 hosts (may be others, I haven't checked yet) that are on the network, and can ping the domain controller.  They can also ping each other.  Yet when I'm on the server, the ping request times out when I attempt to contact their hostnames or IP addresses.

I know it seems like it's not a big deal, but I think that it's a symptom of something else, because the AV management console (also hosted on the DC) cannot reach those IP addresses to push out the AV client.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to troubleshoot. Is the ping being sent? Is it being received? Is a reply being sent? Is the reply being received?

Comment: Are the computers joined to the domain? Did someone firewall them off (incorrectly)?

Comment: Mr. Schwartz, at the risk of sounding like the newbie I am, how do I check for those things?

Comment: Mr. Hampton, they are not joined to the domain, I will check some joined machines in a few minutes. I will also take a look at the firewall rules, I took over a mess of a network, so Im not certain about anything yet

Comment: @DavidLiese: If you don't have some kind of program to tell what packets are being sent or received by your computer and know how to use one, you should pass this problem off to a network administrator who knows how to troubleshoot. Otherwise, you need to learn how to tell what network traffic is being sent and received to figure out where the process is breaking down. For a ping to work, about a dozen things have to happen, and you need to run down that process one by one to see which thing is not happening.